# Is there a Autofac integration library for WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, autofac

I am working  on a Win form application with Autofac
Here we resolve the dependencies as following:
As seen in [doc](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html)

```
using (var scope = DIConfig.container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var us = scope.Resolve<IUsersService>();
                usersGrid.DataSource = us.GetUsers();
            }
```

However in Web MVC project we could resolve all dependencies 
Eg as in

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

So that there is no need to resolve the scope each time as in 
and use the simple code

```
usersGrid.DataSource = us.GetUsers();
```

How could we do a similar resolution in Winform so that there is no need of more code in use? How to Resolve dependency in Winforms?Is there a [Autofac integration library](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/index.html) for WinForm ?

Comment: What is the lifetime of the created (eg. IUserService) components within the scope - eg. are they "per Application" or "per Window" or "per User Operation" or other?

Comment: @user2864740 It would be per User Operation for now but, per Application might be needed for some other cases.

Comment: I would create separate scopes then - the application / form scope would install itself using Property Injection in the applicable Application / Form load. Any per operation scope would following the using form above (but could itself be property injected): `using (var scope = CreateSomeCustomNamedScope()) { var us = scope.Resolve<..> }`. It's a little bit of a bleed but not much. The bleed can be isolated by putting the action body in it's own injected type that acts as the root. You can also create a "method DI injector" that performs a method call and injects components, as well.

Answer (score 10):

I've successfully migrated a WinForms application to use `Autofac` in the near past. I wanted a design which has the following motivations.

- Find a suitable scope similar to a web request in case of an ASP.NET MVC application for example
- Be as abstract as possible to avoid the service locator pattern

I came up with choosing a `Form` to serve as a scope, so for example if I inject a view model or a repository, it should get disposed when the form is closed, etc. This way I can use constructor injection in my `Form`s just as in `Controller`s in a web app. For example

```
public class UserEditForm : Form {

    private reaodnly UserEditViewModel viewModel;

    public UserEditForm(UserEditViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel= viewModel;
    }

    public void Load(int userId) {
        this.viewModel.Load(userId);
    }

    ...
}

public class UserEditViewModel {

    private readonly UserRepository repository;

    public UserEditViewModel(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    ...
}
```

To avoid the service locator pattern as much as possible, I've designed an `IFormFactory` interface which looks as simple as this.

```
public interface IFormFactory
{
    Form CreateForm(Type formType);
}
```

I decided to allow accessing this statically thorough the UI layer (but only there), so I've implemented the following static class.

```
public static class FormFactory
{
    private static IFormFactory factory;

    public static void Use(IFormFactory factory)
    {
        if (FormFactory.factory != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(@"Form factory has been already set up.");
        }

        FormFactory.factory = factory;
    }

    public static Form Create(Type formType)
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(@"Form factory has not been set up. Call the 'Use' method to inject an IFormFactory instance.");
        }

        return factory.CreateForm(formType);
    }

    public static T Create<T>() where T : Form
    {
        return (T)Create(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Now at this point I abstracted the creation process of forms. Note, that until this point I didn't even care about any potantial DI container. Here I already could start refactoring the entire view layer to use this pattern, for example like this.

```
using (var form = FormFactory.Create<UserEditorForm>()) {
    form.Load(userId);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

And here came Autofac (or any other DI container). I've implemented the `IFormFactory` using Autofac like this.

```
public class AutofacFormFactory : IFormFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope currentScope;

    public AutofacFormFactory(ILifetimeScope currentScope)
    {
        this.currentScope = currentScope;
    }

    public Form CreateForm(Type formType)
    {
        // begin a new lifetime scope for each form instance
        var scope = this.currentScope.BeginLifetimeScope();

        var form = (Form) scope.Resolve(formType);

        form.Disposed += (s, e) =>
        {
            // finish the scope when the form is disposed (closed)
            scope.Dispose();
        };

        return form;
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to include the binding in the Autofac configuration.

```
builder.RegisterType<AutofacFormFactory>().As<IFormFactory>();
```

Then finally I initialize this all at `Program.cs` like this.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();

var container = builder.Build();

FormFactory.Use(container.Resolve<IFormFactory>());
```

Hope it can still be helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in general, for a WinForms or other *non-request based* application, using a specific scope with `using` is appropriate: when needing operation-specific components.

### Divy up the component lifetimes

The first step, is to first identify components that can be resolved for the entire application - trivially this includes "singleton" services, of which a good chunk should be. These components are added to the default Autofac scope builder.

Then each form (eg. in the OnLoad event) uses *property injection* to load the form/application-wide components that it requires - this can itself be wrapped in a global method, but keeps knowing the Container to *one place* in the Form to avoid a Service Locator pattern bleed.

(If all the Forms are created via the IoC container then constructor injection can also be used; I've found that using property injection is "sufficient" for WinForms and WebForms.)

### Resolve from the injected "OperationScope" component

One of the injected components knows how to create the appropriate *operation scopes*. In this case the injected property might be the following, where IOperationScope is an ILifetimeScope that handles the "operation UoW", whatever that may be. This scope *replaces the pre-request scope* as found in MVC/WCF:

```
public Func<IOperationScope> BeginOperationScope { get; set; }
```

(The OperationScope should probably be a *named scope* so that components can be registered to just this named scope, instead of globally.)

Then in the operation itself, we have:

```
using (var op = BeginOperationScope())
{
    op.Resolve<..>(..);
}
```

This has a bit of bleed in that there is still a Resolve directly in the WinForm event code - it's not terrible, but still leaves the feeling of not-DI (as it's a very slight SL bleed) and mixing-UI-and-logic.

#### Variant 1: Create a method-injection-resolver

It is possible to create a simple method-injection-resolver so that the actual code could be called as so:

```
public void OperationMethod(ISomeOperationService service)
{
   // "method parameter injection"
}

using (var op = BeginOperationScope())
{
   op.ExecuteMethod(OperationMethod);
}
```

There is no standard form of this method-injection-resolver but it can be written with just a little bit of reflection for a trivial case.

While at first this might appear to be a duplicate method per Event, it actually helps add isolation between the UI and any "Controller" logic established. The UI events then only wrap to the applicable logic methods that have dependencies resolved automatically.

#### Variant 2: Make the "scope" a Controller for the action

In this case the scope itself might simply be an injected disposable Component with a *composite ILifetimeScope* that it created, used to inject components, and cleans up itself in `Dispose`.

```
using (var op = BeginOperationScope())
{
   op.DoSomething();
}
```

This case is arguably the most "pure" and it has a nice separation. However, it should still be noted that the `using` approach is *still* used and the Controller/scope itself controls the applicable per-Operation Autofac lifetime.

Since the lifetime is still limited to the operation, make sure *not* to bleed IQueryable or non-forced/lazy IEnumerable objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Autofac in WinForms easily. Just create and build a container and make it accessible where it needs to be accessible.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register individual components
builder.RegisterInstance(new SomeRepository)
       .As<ISomeRepository>();

var container = builder.Build();
```

and then resolve what you need from the container.

MVC uses a built in DependencyResolver to facilitate resolving things in the MVC world, but basically it is the same concept under the hood.

You can check the autofac doc [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html) and also read about the DependencyResolver in MVC [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html).

Comment: This is likely what the OP is already doing and it does not appear to address the OPs question relating to lifetime management of the scope; the question implies (but doesn't explicitly show) the use of a UoW context. In MVC/WCF/etc it's simply "one scope per request injected into controllers" - but that doesn't exist in WinForms.