# Can dependency injection be implemented to windows library projects?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, lib

Can dependency injection be implemented to windows library projects? Or this design pattern is not practiced in libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by "windows library"?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can.

Microsoft for example does that with all their ASP.NET Core libraries. They all support dependency injection.

The important part for ease-of-use is to make sure the library knows how to wire-up the dependencies. For example, the Microsoft libraries all provide extension methods for the `ServiceCollection`, so I can write `serviceCollection.AddLibraryName();` instead of having to add all the required classes myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. you can do Asp.net core same as windows forms without other lib like autofac(if you want to use you can also)  and  .net with like https://autofac.org/ you can as much as you can register you services, repo, singletons.

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register individual components
builder.RegisterInstance(new TaskRepository())
       .As<ITaskRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<TaskController>();
builder.Register(c => new LogManager(DateTime.Now))
       .As<ILogger>();

// Scan an assembly for components
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(myAssembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();

var container = builder.Build();
```

**UPDATE**

```
    static class Program {
    private static Container container;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Bootstrap();
        Application.Run(container.GetInstance<Form1>());
    }

    private static void Bootstrap() {
        // Create the container as usual.
        container = new Container();

        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<IUserContext, WinFormsUserContext>();
        container.Register<Form1>();

        // Optionally verify the container.
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

And we can use like this.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;
    private readonly IUserContext userContext;

    public Form1(IUserRepository userRepository, IUserContext userContext) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userContext = userContext;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (this.userContext.IsAdministrator) {
            this.userRepository.ControlSomeStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763242/is-there-a-autofac-integration-library-for-winform

Comment: Where do I write above registration code in library where there is no entry point?

Comment: @bill update my code. like this u can register your repos and services in startup class.